# Why am I missing "META-INF" folder in my apk in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, apk, meta-inf

I have signed my apk. But META-INF folder is missing.
Please help me fix this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to generate signed apk with command (windows cmd)

create a key using

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

then sign the apk using :

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk alias_name
```